# Compare and replace items in a string

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I am looking for help on a problem that's got me stumped. I have several lines that look like this

```
line = '{2}*{3}^2'
```

The numbers in curly brackets have a mapping in a dictionary, where the dictionary will look something like this

```
factorseq_dict = [('2', 'NAME1'), ('3', 'NAME2')]
```

What I'm looking for is a script that will read through each key (numbers in bracket) in line and look for the corresponding value in the dictionary. This value will then be used to create a new mylist, meanwhile keeping everything else in the original line constant. So my new content will change line to newline as follows.

```
line = '{2}*{3}^2'
newline = '{NAME1}*{NAME2}^2'
```

I've got the dictionary created but really struggling with the rest of the logic as I cannot separate the items that are in the curly brackets with the normal digits so I'm sorry I can't provide any code example.

The closest I got is to get my items but after that I'm stumped

```
line='{2}*{3}^2'
elements = re.split('({[^}]*})', line)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may pass an anonymous function inside the replacement part of `re.sub` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '{2}*{3}^2'
>>> factorseq_dict = [('2', 'NAME1'), ('3', 'NAME2')]
>>> dict_ = dict(factorseq_dict)
>>> re.sub(r'\{(\d+)\}', lambda m: '{' + dict_[m.group(1)] + '}', line)
'{NAME1}*{NAME2}^2'
```

A bit explanation of the re.sub function in this case-

```
dict_ = {'3': 'NAME2', '2': 'NAME1'}
```

> pattern  r'{(\d+)}' will extract '2' or '3' and pass to lambda and
>   this match object will act as dictionary key to return value from the
>   dictionary dict_ e.g. dict_['2'] returns 'NAME1' (added braces returns {NAME1} etc) that will be used in the **line** string to replace {2} or {3}. After all we get **'{NAME1}*{NAME2}^2'**

Comment: Thanks Avinash. Works a treat.